# JPA parent child relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a scenario where I need to load all the child values in one case and some specific child values in other . I am using a single bean for both the cases and writing the queries using named query.

```
@namedqueries{
@namedQuery(name="query1") = "select parent from Parent parent",
@namedQuery(name="query2") = "select parent from Parent parent",
}
Class Parent {

@manytomany
@join mentioned my join condition here // 
 List<Child> child ; 

}

Class Child 
{ 
 String A;
 String B;
 String C;

 @manytomany(mappedby = "child")
 List<parent> parent ; 
 }
```

Now in my query 2 I need to load only String A not String B and String C .
I tried using

```
"select parent.child .A from Parent parent" as Query 2
```

but getting the below error

```
 "Attempting to navigate to relation field via multi-valued association and
 jpql doesnt  allow traversal through multi valued relationship. Try join instead"
```

So any suggestions on how to proceed on this ..

```
1) Should I have to create a new bean for each Query
2) Or Can we control the child object parameters in specific named queries
```

Comment: You can't do that at all.  The Child entity is always going to contain all of the contents it has in the database.

Comment: Oh @Affe so creating new beans only with required parameter's the only solution . In the case above creating two beans for "child" and "parent"

Comment: use the 'WHERE' clause to select by attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing a collection when you say `select parent.child` and you can't say `select parent.child.A` this is wrong according HQL standards. You need to do this using join as the error message is suggesting:

```
select c.A from parent as p join p.child as c
```

Then no, you don't have to create a new bean for each query.